# Defining custom Grunt tasks and chain them with others

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var config = {
    shell: {
      ...
    },
    copy: {
      ...
    }
  };
  grunt.initConfig(config);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:compile', 'copy:jsfiles']);
};
```

I am using `grunt-contrib-x` components which can be configured and then registered in a task as part of a chain.

### What about a custom task?

I need to add another task whose work is performed by a function:

```
var customTask = function() {
  // This will do something...
};
```

I need to run it after `shell:compile` and `copy:jsfiles` as part of another task, and also in other chains. I would like to have the same pattern and being able to do something like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var config = {
    shell: { ... }, copy: { ... },
    customTask: function() {
      // Doing stuff
    }
  };
  // ... some code ...
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:compile', 'copy:jsfiles']);
  grunt.registerTask('advanced', ['shell:compile', 'copy:jsfiles', 'customTask']);
  grunt.registerTask('advanced2', ['shell:compileComponent', 'copy:jsfilesComponent', 'customTask']);
};
```

The goal is having the possibility to create task chains and include my custom task as part of a list of sequential tasks to be executed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Creating tasks in Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks). Also it seems like you have the right idea- -- what is wrong with what you are doing now?

Comment: That is not working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `grunt.registerTask` and pass in a name as the first argument and the function to run as the last argument.

```
grunt.registerTask('myTask', function () {
  //do some stuff
});
```

Then you can chain it

```
grunt.registerTask('advanced', ['shell:compile', 'copy:jsfiles', 'myTask']);
```

Basically it's the same as in your example, except you define your custom task as a parameter to `grunt.registerTask`, not as a property in the config.

http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks